# Google Maps IOS Sdk shows [?][?] for Myanmar and Ethiopia

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, swift

I'm using  Google Maps IOS SDK  1.9.13516.0 , the city names in Myanmar are shown as [?][?] on the Map instead of the local Burmese font.

According to Google doc for Google Maps this issue was fixed in version 1.8.0 (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases)

-The Google Maps SDK for iOS now includes fonts for languages currently unsupported by the iOS system, such as Khmer. (Issue 5228)

These fonts may be safely removed from your GoogleMaps.framework if you have no interest in these regions, but some text may render as "[?]".

I have written the App in **Swift**, also  tested this in **OBJ-C**   and even  the official **SDKDemos** shows this same issue.

The Official Google Map app for IOS  shows  text with Burmese font correctly

How can this be fixed ?

[image: Myanmar]

Comment: I'm looking right now in GMSCoreResources.bundle and there is `Siemreap.ttf` (Khmer) font - so ....  what is your system region/language settings for the simulator or device?

Comment: @TonyMkenu I tried it on simulator (Iphone 5s) and Devices :  IPhone 4s 8.1.2 , IPhone 6 Plus 8.1.2 , and Iphone 5 8.1.2  Locale en_IN , en_US

Comment: @TonyMkenu The  Siemreap.ttf is present in my project under  GoogleMaps.bundle > GMSCoreResources.bundle > Siemreap.ttf , also GoogleMaps.bundle is present under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources >GoogleMaps.bundle

Comment: @TonyMkenu bug fixed in new sdk 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue Fixed in New version of Google Maps IOS SDK

Version 1.9.2 - February 2015

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Resolved Issues:

```
Show correct characters for Myanmar place labels. (Issue 7576)
Fixed a small memory leak related to font registration. (Issue 7559)
```

I had filed an issue at gmaps-api-issues regarding this problem. 
( https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7576)

They have fixed it in the new SDK 1.9.2 , it was an internal bug.